# Rails Basecamp style subdomains best practice

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, multi-tenant

My goal is to have separate user accounts for each subdomain.  Under no circumstance do I want cross-pollination between subdomains.

I've looked over [Robby Russle](http://www.robbyonrails.com/articles/2009/01/11/subdomain-accounts-with-ruby-on-rails-explained), and [DHH's](http://37signals.com/svn/posts/1512-how-to-do-basecamp-style-subdomains-in-rails) thoughts (both are pre-Rails3 though).

The controller handling is pretty straight forward, my questions is about keeping the model's data separated.  What's the best way to keep user1 from seeing user2's data?

Some idea's might include:

1. Add a `subdomain_id` foreign key to every model - *Advantage*, simple one-to-many relationship can be used to scope each model to a subdomain. - *Disadvantage*, this is pretty tight coupling between the data and the larger application logic, which seems inappropriate.
2. `One-to-many :through` for each model associating it with a subdomain - *Advantage*, no need to add a `subdomain_id` foreign key column to existing tables associating them with their sub domain.  - *Disadvantage*, My gut feeling is that this is way overkill.  Multiple join queries may get complicated and cross-pollination bugs may occur.
3. Separate applications or databases for each subdomain - *Advantage*, the data is completely segregated. - *Disadvantage*, a large number of individual applications/databases will need to be managed/updated/secured/hosted/etc.
4. Your idea?

Answer (score 7):

Option 5. [Guy Naor's Schema solution](http://aac2009.confreaks.com/videos/111-aac2009-writing-multi-tenant-applications-in-rails) - *Advantage*, This just blew my mind. Mostly transparent to rails, COMPLETE data separation, only one database, works really great for applications that weren't originally designed as multi-tenant. a-mazing.  - *Disadvantage*, need to be using Postgres, or some other database that supports schemas (I'm already using PG anyway), you'll need to iterate over existing schemas when you migrate.

Right now this seems far and away the best way.  Are there any major drawbacks?.

Comment: +1 for PG schemas. I've been using this in Django to great effect, and am about to delve into it with Rails. From what I hear Rails 3 makes subdomains [much easier](http://railscasts.com/episodes/221-subdomains-in-rails-3) (don't need a plugin anymore) so this is almost a no brainer. Of course, you can also use subdirectories instead of subdomains.

Comment: Glad to hear a little encouragement.  Seems like everyone (37signals included) is using the 'scope' approach.  IMO, that gets really complex if you have a very rich model ecosystem in your app with more than a few relationships.

Comment: I'm using the scope approach but wish I'd seen this first.

Answer (score 1):

If you're sure the object-to-subdomain relation will always be one-to-one, I would pick option 1. If objects might be related to multiple subdomains in the future you're bound to option 2. It incurs more overhead, but it's easily managed when using something like cancan.

I would stay away from option 3 for the reasons you mentioned. Rails doesn't do multiple databases well and besides, using multiple databases in one application doesn't guarantee any more security than the other options.

Comment: Addition to my own post 5 years later: the apartment gem (https://github.com/influitive/apartment) provides a really useful way to add multi-tenancy to a Rails application. It's been our preferred method for a while (using Postgres schemas) and it works really well.